# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join exeption

Tags: java, postgresql, jpql

I'm trying to write jpql query with hibernate. I have such query in @Repository

```
@Query(value = "select p from Product p inner join ProductsUser pu on p.prosuctId = pu.productId where pu.userId = :uuid")
```

But I get an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select p from com.example.api.dto.ProductDto p inner join ProductsUsersDto pu on p.prosuctId = pu.productId where pu.userId = :uuid]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify `JOIN ... ON`-clause since it's already configured in Entity classes. So query is bit simpler, like this:

```
@Query("select p from Product p join p.productsUser pu where pu.userId = :uuid")
```